# Cannot open Firefox in Ubuntu22.04

Tags: software-installation, firefox, 22.04

I just downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 on a MacBook and would like to install Firefox. I've tried different installation commands such as:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

and:

```
sudo snap install firefox
```

but I still cannot open Firefox and the error message is shown in the picture:

[image: Error code when opening Firefox]

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Is it a server?

Comment: I used UTM. I just solved this issue by installing Firefox without snap. But another error occurs, stating that "Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: VA-API test failed: failed to initialise VAAPI connection."